# How do find integer solutions to this special linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the computationally most efficient way to find integer solutions $\mathbf {X}$ for the following linear system

$$\mathbf {Xa = c}$$

given the following constraints?

- $\mathbf a$ is of dimension $n \times 1$,
- $\mathbf c$ is of dimension $m \times 1$,
- $\mathbf X$ is of dimension $m \times n$,
- $n >= m$
- $\mathbf {X}$ can only have 1 or 0 as elements
- $\mathbf {a}$ and $\mathbf {c}$ only have <strike>finite decimal numbers</strike> integers as elements
- Sum of elements in $\mathbf {a}$ equals to the sum of elements in $\mathbf {c}$
- There must be one and only one 1 in every column of $\mathbf {X}$

The practical problem I am trying to solve is to find all the many-to-1 maps (functions) between two finite list of numbers such that y is the sum of all its preimages. For example:

- list_A: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
- list_B: 5, 5', 6 (adding a prime sign to the second 5 to distinguish it from the first 5)

Then there will be two solutions:

1. f(1) = 5, f(2) = 5', f(3) = 5', f(4) = 5, f(6) = 6
2. f(1) = 5', f(2) = 5, f(3) = 5, f(4) = 5', f(6) = 6

To put this example in the language of the above problem, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ are:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
6 \\
\end{pmatrix},
  \mathbf c = \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
5 \\
6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

And there are two solutions:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf X_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0  \\
0&1&1&0&0  \\
0&0&0&0&1  \\
\end{pmatrix},
  \mathbf X_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0  \\
1&0&0&1&0  \\
0&0&0&0&1  \\
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}

And of course there are cases where there exists no solution. For example:

- list_A: 1, 2, 3, 4
- list_B: 1, 2, 3, 5

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{pmatrix},
  \mathbf c = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Please take one of your examples, such as the last one with no solutions, and type in the $X,a,c$ to show what elements are given and what need to be found.  I can't follow the later part of the discussion.

Comment: your constraint on $c$ doesn't make sense. $Xa$ produces an $ m \times 1$ vector.

Comment: What do you mean by "finite decimal numbers"?  Integers?  If they are rationals, you might as well multiply by a common denominator to get $a$ and $c$ in integers.

Comment: Will Jagy, RHowe, Robert Israel: Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my original post.